# Sum of continuous sequences

Tags: algorithm

Given an array A with N elements, I want to find the sum of minimum elements in all the possible contiguous sub-sequences of A. I know if N is small we can look for all possible sub sequences but as N is upto 10^5 what can be best way to find this sum?

Example: Let N=3 and A[1,2,3] then ans is 10 as Possible contiguous sub sequences {(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(1,2,3),(2,3)} so Sum of minimum elements = 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 10

Comment: Given set A has numbers sorted or they've no orders?

Comment: @L16H7 Their is no such order

Comment: Can you give the expected results for [1,2,2,3,5,5,5,6,6,7]?

Comment: @L16H7 Its {1}+min{1,2}+min{1,2,2}+min{1,2,2,3}+min{1,2,2,3,5} and so on

Comment: But 3 and 5 are not continuous, why did you consider min{1,2,2,3,5}?

Comment: Shouldn't it be **{1}** + min{1,2} + min{1,2,3} + min{1,2,2} + min{1,2,2,3} + **{2}** + min{2,3} + min{2,2} + min{2,2,3} + **{3}** + **{5}** + min{5,6} + min{5,6,7} + min{5,6,6} + min{5,6,6,7} + min{5,5} + min{5,5,6} + min{5,5,6,7} + min{5,5,6,6} + min{5,5,6,6,7} + min{5,5,5} + min{5,5,5,6} + min{5,5,5,6,7} + min{5,5,5,6,6} + min{5,5,5,6,6,7} + **{6}** + {6,7} + min{6,6} + min{6,6,7} + **{7}**? A bold set shows that the sets next to it has same minimum value. Any mistakes in above sub-sequences?

Comment: Are identical subsequences (repeating patterns in the string) considered as distinct or not?  eg, for the input A[1, 1, 1], is the answer 3 or 6?

Answer (score 5):

- Let's fix one element(`a[i]`). We want to know the position of the rightmost element smaller than this one located to the left from `i`(`L`). We also need to know the position of the leftmost element smaller than this one located to the right from `i`(`R`).
- If we know `L` and `R`, we should add `(i - L) * (R - i) * a[i]` to the answer.
- It is possible to precompute `L` and `R` for all `i` in linear time using a stack. Pseudo code:

  ```
  s = new Stack
  L = new int[n]
  fill(L, -1)
  for i <- 0 ... n - 1:
      while !s.isEmpty() && s.top().first > a[i]:
          s.pop()
      if !s.isEmpty():
          L[i] = s.top().second
      s.push(pair(a[i], i))
  ```

  We can reverse the array and run the same algorithm to find `R`.
- How to deal with equal elements? Let's assume that `a[i]` is a pair `<a[i], i>`. All elements are distinct now.

The time complexity is `O(n)`.

Here is a full pseudo code(I assume that `int` can hold any integer value here, you should
choose a feasible type to avoid an overflow in a real code. I also assume that all elements are distinct):

```
int[] getLeftSmallerElementPositions(int[] a):
    s = new Stack
    L = new int[n]
    fill(L, -1)
    for i <- 0 ... n - 1:
        while !s.isEmpty() && s.top().first > a[i]:
            s.pop()
        if !s.isEmpty():
            L[i] = s.top().second
        s.push(pair(a[i], i))
    return L

int[] getRightSmallerElementPositions(int[] a):
    R = getLeftSmallerElementPositions(reversed(a))
    for i <- 0 ... n - 1:
        R[i] = n - 1 - R[i]
    return reversed(R)

int findSum(int[] a):
    L = getLeftSmallerElementPositions(a)
    R = getRightSmallerElementPositions(a)
    int res = 0
    for i <- 0 ... n - 1:
        res += (i - L[i]) * (R[i] - i) * a[i]
    return res
```

Comment: @kraskevich Can you add whole pseudocode ? It makes things more clear

Comment: You had assumed 1 based indexing ?

Comment: @user3840069 I use 0-based indices. I have also just added a full pseudo code.

Comment: It gives L[]={0,0,1} and R={0,1,2} . Is this what you mean by these 2 arrays ?

Comment: I think this answer owes an explanation of why it works. Something like: element i is the minimum of all substrings a[l..r] with L[i] < l <= i <= r < R[i]. The number of those substrings is how often we have to add a[i]

Comment: @NiklasB. Absolutely. Also some major cases are not handled in pseudocode

Comment: @user3840069 You should really try to understand what kraskevich is writing here and show some effort in implementing it on your own. We can't handhold you all the way, that's not how SO works. The code seems legit to me

Comment: @NiklasB. I had implemented the whole code ..after that only am saying this. He had done if !s.isEmpty() then do L[i] = s.top().second oterwise L[i] would have -1 which will disturb calculations later on

Comment: @user3840069 Give an example where the output is wrong at the very least

Comment: @NiklasB. Also their is nothing like that array has distinct elements .

Comment: @user3840069 To make elements distinct, you can use a pair(a[i], i) instead of a[i] for comparisons(it is mentioned in my answer). And it is a pseudo code, it was not even tested(so it contain some bugs). It's up to you to implement and test it properly.

Comment: @user3840069 No, I didn't do it in pseudo code. Compare where? -everywhere. Just use an array of pairs instead of an array of ints.

Comment: Your second bullet point is just wrong -- it should be `L * R * a[i]`.  Not sure where you got the extra `i`s from.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Subtracting i is necessary because L and R are end points of a segment, they are not lenghts of a segment to the left and to the right.

Comment: @kraskevich: Ah, ok, I was misunderstanding how you were defining them.

Answer (score -1):

If the list is sorted, you can consider all subsets for size 1, then 2, then 3, to N. The algorithm is initially somewhat inefficient, but an optimized version is below. Here's some pseudocode.

```
let A = {1, 2, 3}
let total_sum = 0

for set_size <- 1 to N
    total_sum += sum(A[1:N-(set_size-1)])
```

First, sets with one element:{{1}, {2}, {3}}: sum each of the elements.

Then, sets of two element {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}: sum each element but the last.

Then, sets of three elements {{1, 2, 3}}: sum each element but the last two.

But this algorithm is inefficient. To optimize to O(n), multiply each ith element by N-i and sum (indexing from zero here). The intuition is that the first element is the minimum of N sets, the second element is the minimum of N-1 sets, etc.

I know it's not a python question, but sometimes code helps:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]

# This is [3, 2, 1]
scale = range(len(A), 0, -1) 

# Take the element-wise product of the vectors, and sum
sum(a*b for (a,b) in zip(A, scale))

# Or just use the dot product
np.dot(A, scale)
```

Comment: He's not looking for power sets, and it's not a python question.

Comment: @IVlad updated to more accurately address the type of sets discussed by OP -- my apologies. I've described the core (but inefficient) version of my algorithm in pseudocode since this isn't a python question, and then verbally described the optimization. Hope you don't mind the bit of python at the end. I sincerely believe it will help someone.